# Random Email aliases

Tags: php, email, random, cpanel, email-address

i need to create random/pseudo email address that will be delivered to a real email address.

Each of my registered client will have a unique & standard pseudo address to send there some specific formated emails. 
Example

- david121238732bnash@mydomain.com
- nick32478234234723923@mydomain.com
- ........maybe hundreds ............

Because the number of clients is big I can't manually add so many addresses. I need something dynamic.

All emails will be delivered to info@mydomain.com . Each email will be fetched with PHP, so probably I need IMAP access (cpanel,gmail)

How I can archive it?
Example with random email here https://www.mail-tester.com/

I use cpanel.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're asking how to generate random emails? Or how to archive a copy of every email you send? Or how to map each pseudo email to the real email? What's that link got to do with your question?

Comment: @RyanVincent it's a common system amongst public sites such as gumtree whereby users are given alias email addresses so that users can email each other but are not given each others personal email addresses. Tom, the question is how to automate and setup this generated alias email addresses rather than have to manually do it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - that sounds more useful :)

Comment: First of all I need this to receive emails from automatic forwarders that clients have setup to their emails. So is not for spam!

Should be unique because I need to know which user sends the email. (User may sends from many different emails to specific email my-random-email@dom.com) so everything that delivered to my-random-email@dom.com is will now that is coming from certain user.

Secondly should be random to able to protect the client data. If was info@dom.com probably some other users will send email there. Random email helps not to be guessable from not authorized senders.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to create through cpanel API forwarder
https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/SDK/UAPI+Functions+-+Email::add_forwarder

So actually email address not exists but cpanel forwarder will deliver the email on existing email account.

abcasdsa23423@mydom.com --> UserID:1
a24234a2343453453@mydom.com --> UserID:2
etc

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need random?  Your problem would seem to be solved by unique addresses.  Just use integers: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 827459, 827460, ... 28495723463 etc.  Each number is unique and will not mean a lot to the recipient.

Comment: I'm not offering email service. Must be random to able to know from which client is coming from AND not able to be quested from spammers.

Comment: Then encrypt the numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...  Because encryption is reversible, the encryption of a number will be unique.  Express the result in hex or Base64 to get characters.